# Oracle SQL,range between 1-1000

Tags: sql

I have a table containing numbers, range between 1-1000 they are unique, but I need to identify which of the number are missing in the range 1-1000 from the table using Oracle SQL,

1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10

result 2,7

Could anyone help with a script or URL to a script.?

Comment: What about 11, 12, etc? Aren't they missing too?

Comment: No as the count has not got that high yet but I can use max(SheetNo) as a high point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
select level from dual
connect by level<=1000
minus
select mycolumn from mytable
```

EDIT:

To find out which numbers are missing from the sequence without hardcoded 1000:

```
select level from dual
connect by level < (select max(mycolumn) from mytable)
minus
select mycolumn from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select a.check_number
from (select level check_number from dual connect by level <= 1000) a
where not exists 
(select null from myTable t where a.check_number = t.lookup_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with numbers as (
   select level as i
   from dual 
   connect by level <= (select max(some_number) from your_table)
) 
select nr.i as missing
from numbers nr
  left join your_table yt on yt.some_number = nr.i
where  yt.some_number is null;
```